# Test extreme value distribution in Logit Model

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logit, extreme-value

Suppose I have a Logit regression with error term.
How to test the error term follows an extreme value distribution?

I check [Logistic Regression in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression)
it says

> The choice of the type-1 extreme value distribution seems fairly arbitrary, but it makes the mathematics work out, and it may be possible to justify its use through rational choice theory.

The model in my mind is a discrete choice model in economics. Each individual $i$ has utility
$$
u_{ij} = \delta_j + \varepsilon_{ij}
$$
from good $j=0,1,2...$.
If we assume $\varepsilon_{ij}$ is type-1 extreme value, then the probability the good $j$ will be purchased would be
$$
P_j = \Pr(u_{ij}\ge u_{ij'},\forall j') = \frac{\exp(\delta_j)}{\sum_{j'}\exp(\delta_{j'})}
$$
which indicates that
$$
\log P_j-\log P_0 = \delta_j
$$
If we assume $\log P_0=0$ as consumer's outside option. Further, if we impose that
$$
\delta_j = X_j\beta + \epsilon_j
$$
Then 
$$
\log P_j = X_j\beta + \epsilon_j
$$
In general, $P_j$ is observable as market share of good $j$. Then we can estimate the above equation by OLS.

But anyway, the possibility that we can transfer the above model to OLS is largely depending on that $\varepsilon_{ij}$ is type-1 extreme value. If it is not a crazy assumption, how can we test it?

Comment: Why do you need to determine that? It isn't usually done for LR. In general, it is best to think of LR as not having an error term. (I don't see that quote in the link.)

Comment: @gung my fault. This quote exists in page for LR, not extreme value.

Comment: What kind of data dependent variable do you have? Is it 0 and 1, or continuous $[0,1]$?

Comment: @aksakai It would be a discrete choice model. I add it into the question.

Comment: The distribution of unobservable (structural) error is generally untestable.